# How do you return a response to an Ajax request server side from struts 1.3?

Tags: ajax, jsp, response, struts-1

I would like to integrate some Ajax techniques into an existing struts application.

How do I send the requested data back server side to the client without causing the page to reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you called the server side with Ajax, the page will not reload. You don't have to do anything special on the server side. Although, obviously, you should do your Ajax request to a different page made for that purpose, not to the same page.

Comment: Ok thanks, yeah the requests are being made from client side he's to a server running a struts 1.3 framework. I was worried that when the server processed the forward it would cause the page to reload which would defeat the purpose.

Comment: The forward will only affect the response that is read by your javascript.